# Installing firebase-admin - can't find nopt.js

Tags: node.js, npm, firebase-admin

So I'm trying to install the firebase-admin module (`npm install firebase-admin --save)` inside the "functions"-folder when implementing the firebase cloud functions, but this error-message keeps interrupting the installation. It has something to do with not finding "nopt.js", and I have no idea how to fix it. Has it to do with the node/npm versions? Has anyone had similar problems and were able to solve it?

Here's the error message:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-129-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "firebase-admin"
npm ERR! node v7.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! path /vagrant/functions/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/nopt/bin/nopt.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/vagrant/functions/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/nopt/bin/nopt.js'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/vagrant/functions/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/nopt/bin/nopt.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: Can you try `npm install grpc` and see if that succeeds?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka It didn't. Instead I had to install an older version of firebase-admin (5.3.0 worked)

Comment: Would you mind filing a bug at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node? Please include your environment details: OS, npm version etc